# How to create a function with context

Tags: powershell

I have an array of hashes and want to add a function to the hashes (not a method).  apparently `$this` isn't defined for it:

```
$x=@{ a = @{ p1 = "a"; fn = {$this.p1} } }
```

and I also can't do this:

```
$x.keys |%{ $x[$_].fn = {$x[$_].p1} }
```

because the function is not a closure so at the time I run it `$_` isn't defined to be what it was at the time of creation

the reason I don't want to define it as a method (-membertype scriptmethod) is that I want to call it this way:

```
$x.a.fn "test"
```

which is more Powershellish than:

```
$x.a.fn("test")
```

also I'd prefer not to have to do:

```
& $x.a.fn "test"
```

because users will never remember all those choices (the syntax is too complicated in psh)

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: What is it that you're *really* trying to accomplish here? If you simply do it in 2 steps, the first part of your question is fairly trivial to solve. Second part cannot be done afaik.

Comment: what I'm trying to accomplish is to store a function in an object `$x` and call it like this `$x.myfunction "params"`

Comment: Yes, *but for what purpose*? What you want can't be done, I'm trying to figure out whether what you ultimately want to achieve by doing so can be solved another way

Comment: `$x.myfunction "params"` this is incorrect syntax from PowerShell point of view. If you want to have command defined by expression (like `$x.a.fn`), then it should be prefixed by invocation operator (`&` or `.`). Otherwise command should be [`BareWord`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.language.stringconstanttype.aspx) string constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so apparently Psh has closures! so I can do something like this:

```
$x=@{ p1 = "a"; }
$x.fn = {$x.p1}.GetNewClosure();
```

and then call it like this:

```
&$x.fn
```